# How to edit the "lists" defined in Bullets & Numbering in paragraph styles?

Tags: adobe-indesign

The "Bullets & numbering" section of InDesign paragraph styles lets you create "Lists" and give them a name and properties around how and when they restart numbering.

Once a "list" is created, how do I see its properties, or edit it, or delete it? How do I manage this list of lists? All I can find is an option to create lists and choose them, nothing to edit them or delete them. (CS6)

[image]

By "Properties" I mean the three properties defined when you create the list in this dialogue above:

1. List Name
2. Is "Continue...stories" ticked yes/no
3. Is "Continue...book" ticked yes/no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit a defined list***

- Choose Type > Bulleted And Numbered Lists > Define Lists.
- Select a list and click Edit.
- Enter a new name for the list or change your selection of Continue Numbers options.

Note: Paragraph styles that are assigned to the list are reassigned to the list under its new name.

***Delete a defined list***

- Choose Type > Bulleted And Numbered Lists > Define Lists.
- Select a list.
- Click Delete, and then select a different list or the [Default] list to replace your list with.

Answer (score 1):

Lists do not have properties, they group things together. You can pick lists for that reason in the paragraph styles. And you *Customize the appearance of a numbered list*

Lists themselves can be found here: `Type > Bulleted & Numbered Lists > Define Lists`

Tutorial: 
https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/create-bulleted-numbered-lists.html

Help:
https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/bullets-numbering.html

Comment: By "Properties" I mean a) list name b) is "Continue...stories" ticked yes/no c) is "Continue...book" ticked yes/no - the three things you  set on creating a list, visible in the screenshot

Comment: Type > Bulleted & Numbered Lists

Comment: Great, `Type > Bulleted & Numbered Lists > Define Lists` answers the question, thanks - why not put that as your answer?

Comment: Done. The exact location I didn't know either, but I knew they documented it well. Adobe actually has a rather good help site.